# How to retrieve url of the image uploaded on Amazon S3

Tags: c#, .net, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon S3. I want to upload all my images / PDF to S3 and let the user access those by using the URL. I am reading up the documentation and landed on this page:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html

This sample only uploads the image. How would I get the URL of the uploaded image so I can store them in my database and my user can use them to view the image?

For eg. Shouldn't it offer some url like `http://aws.amazon.com/bucket-name/image-name.jpg` and then I can type in that url in the browser and view my uploaded image from amazon.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that be in `PutObjectResponse` that is returned in `response2`?

Comment: No, I am unable to see. Here is what the class offers http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_PutObjectResponse.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon don't give you the URL because the structure is already know before you upload a file.

```
http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>
```

Comment: Note that the second form `http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>` is only valid for buckets in the us-east-1 region.  Requests to this endpoint for buckets in other regions return an XML error stating that `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint...` An alternate endpoint is included in the message, and is usually the `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` endpoint,  but this can vary.

Answer (score 3):

You already know the bucket name, and the object name when you do the upload - S3 doesn't need to 'tell' you anything, you have the information - in fact you told S3 what the file name will be.

Comment: Ahh - silly me. I am now able to wrap my head around the concepts.